# jQuery SlideDown and Up - Firefox issue

Tags: jquery, slideup

I'm having an issue with Firefox and the contents of a fieldset overlapping the content beneath when shown/hidden using slideUp and slideDown.

The fieldset has some paragraphs containing form elements. When it's first shown using slideDown, the form content appears to overlay the content beneath as the fieldset slides into view. The same happens in reverse with slideUp.

Anyone know why this may be the case?

Edit: Testing in Chrome, Safari and IE, and it works fine in these browsers. Definitely FF specific.

Comment: Firefox bug still not fixed in current version - https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=261037

Answer (score 1):

I'm having the same issue. It's because in Firefox, Fieldset isn't affected by overflow:hidden lame...

Just apply the following and see for yourself:

```
fieldset{
height:50px
overflow: hidden;
}
```

Solution... Use a div

Answer (score -1):

```
$("selector").slideDown('slow',function(){
    //call here your slide up functionality here
})
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. I wrap the slideUp function within the slideDown?